# Creating correct hasMany / belongsToMany relationship with Sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I have two models, `Room` and `Day`, that I want to associate.

`day.model.js`

- id
- eventId
- date

`room.model.js`

- id
- eventId
- title

The two need to be associated by the `eventId` property, which is the primary key for a third model.

I need all room instances to be included in all day instances as a day can have many rooms.

My associates are currently set up like so:

```
models.Room.relate = {};

// A room can have many days
models.Room.relate.days = {
  model: models.Day, as: 'days', foreignKey: 'eventId',
};

models.Room.belongsTo(
  models.Day, models.Room.relate.days
);



models.Day.relate = {};

// A day can have many rooms
models.Day.relate.rooms = {
  model: models.Room, as: 'rooms', foreignKey: 'eventId',
};

models.Day.hasMany(
  models.Room, models.Day.relate.rooms
);
```

However I try it I cannot get all Rooms included in all days.

I have tried combinations of all relationships, and even tried adding a `targetKey` property. Perhaps I am missing something.

If anyone can help I'd greatly appreciate it. Many thanks.

Comment: Can you show me the event model as well?